# Excel macro - please xplain this code

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

```
If data_version < 2.11 Then
        Range("A10").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A17").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Resume Path Information"

        Range("A12:B12").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A18").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Server Path:"
        Range("B18") = ""

        Dim formula As String
        Dim cu_row As Integer     

         cu_row = 5
            Do
                'Fix cell to add resume server path
                If Len(Trim(Worksheets("People").Cells(cu_row, ResumeFile).Value)) > 0 Then
                    formula = "=Process!B$18 & """ & Right(Worksheets("People").Cells(cu_row, ResumeFile).Value, Len(Worksheets("People").Cells(cu_row, ResumeFile).Value) - 2) & """"
                    Worksheets("People").Cells(cu_row, ResumeFile).formula = formula

                'Else be sure it is blank
                Else
                    Worksheets("People").Cells(cu_row, ResumeFile).ClearContents
                End If

                cu_row = cu_row + 1

            Loop Until Worksheets("People").Cells(cu_row, 1) = ""
            Range("A1").Select
        End If
```

Comment: Without seeing the format of, and explanation of the cells (and semantics) of the spreadsheet that it is supposed to operate on, it would difficult to explain. Obviously, there is a worksheet named "People" invovled, and it starts at row 5, but I'm assuming that the variable "ResumeFile" is set outside this routine, and refers to a particular column in the sheet that you are looking to mangle in each row until you find a row with a blank cell in the first column.

Comment: What is this expected to do anyway? It _seems_ to catenate data from different worksheets.

Comment: Just edited the code..please have a look again ..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, strictly it doesn't do anything because you've got a trailing `End If` that doesn't match any earlier `If`. But ...

It looks at successive rows of the worksheet called "People", starting in row 5 and stopping when it finds a row with nothing in the first column. For each row, it looks in the column whose number is in variable `ResumeFile`. If there's nothing but whitespace there, it clears it completely. Otherwise, it throws away the first two characters, and interpolates the rest into the magic string `Process!B$18 & "VALUE_GOES_HERE"`, which it stores (as a formula) into the same cell. Here, `&` performs string concatenation.

Finally, it selects cell A1 for some reason.

So, if that column of the worksheet contained "Fred", "Jim" and "Sheila" before, and if cell B18 of the "Process" worksheet contains "Boo!", then you'll get "Boo!ed", "Boo!m" and "Boo!eila".

Comment: OK, I looked again. I think the only difference the changes make to what I said is that there's no longer an unmatched trailing `End If`.

Comment: but B18 in process sheet has serverpath

Comment: No, B18 in whatever sheet was current at the start of the code (maybe it's the one called "Process", but there's nothing in the code to guarantee that) has an empty string. Or am I confused about the effect of `Range("B18") = ""`? (I don't have a copy of Excel convenient to hand right now.)